# How to create different "xsd namespace" for stylesheet and result?

Tags: xslt, namespaces, rdf

Is it possible to transform the xsd namespace to something different in the result?

the input namespace of the xsl:stylesheet element looks like:

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

and the output namespace of the output root element should look like:

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
```

I tried to manually asssign the second namespace to the root element of my output, however then the XSLT transformation does not recognize the elements prefixed with "xsd" anymore, as it seems to overwrite the original namespace.

Changing the prefix and making an alias is also not an option: also in the output (RDF/XML) the prefix of the element should be called "xsd".

Thank you for helping.

EDIT:

here are the relevant parts of the two files:

Input File (XSD):

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

should become

Output File (RDF/XML):

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
```

Comment: If you find an answer to your question, please add it as an answer and mark the answer that works best for you as accepted (click the checkmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

It took me some hours but eventually I figured out a solution on my own:

I firstly had to exclude the prefix of the stylesheet from the results file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xsd">
```

Then I created a new XSD namespace for the root element of the output:

```
<xsl:namespace name="xsd" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#'"/>
```

Anyway, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform all elements in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` to be in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#` then use

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If that does not help then please show us a sample of the input XML you have and the corresponding output sample you want to create.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my question maybe it is more clear now